# Frobenius Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, frobenius-method

We have been given a Hermite equation 
$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} -2x \frac{dy}{dx}+2ny=0$

We need to use the Frobenius method to solve.

So far we have solved the indicial equation and got r = 0,1 and the recurrence relation as $$C_{m+2}=\frac{2(m+r-n)C_{m}}{(m+r+2)(m+r+1)}$$

We know that all odd m>0 are all vanishing terms.

The question i have is why the power series reduces to a polynomial, to a polynomial when r=1 and with n odd and n=1.